Get taxonomy description as "rich text" or formatted text

Sorry I'm quite new at coding, and also working with WordPress and ACF, and I'm trying my best but I can't figure this out:
I'm trying to load my taxonomy description in rich text.
Currently I'm using this code:


<?php
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'locatie'); // Get the terms associated with the post
if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) :
    foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
        <h2><?php echo ($term->name); ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo ($term->description); ?></p>
    <?php endforeach;
endif;
?>



I want to put in location information, add some line breaks, maybe use HTML, and add a link to Google Maps or something. I downloaded a plugin to enable a rich text editing within the taxonomy, and formatted it correctly. However, the code return is without all the formatting. How can I make sure that the formatted, rich text/html description is loaded?
Any suggestions are more then welcome <3


So after some coding, and some testing and stuff I finally got it working. I noticed that the Term description was being stored in the database as escaped HTML entities (<br>), which means WordPress is storing the <br> tags as text, not as actual HTML.
So I wrote some code to decode the HTML entities to actual bring back the proper <br> tags!
<?php
// Temporarily remove all filters on term_description
remove_all_filters('term_description');

// Get terms associated with the post
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'locatie'); 
if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) :
    foreach ($terms as $term) :
        // Decode HTML entities to get actual <br> tags
        $decoded_description = html_entity_decode($term->description);
        ?>
        <p>
            <b><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></b><br>
            <?php echo wp_kses_post($decoded_description); ?><br>
            <?php echo esc_html($term->adresveld); ?>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach;
endif;

// Re-add the filters for term_description if needed
add_filter('term_description', 'wpautop');
?>


I think what's holding you down there is that esc_html(...) function.
It exactly counteracts what you want to achieve.
You want the raw, non-escaped version of your string value. I assume that what your 'description' field returns looks something like this <p>Hello world!</p><br>.
What esc_html does with that is called "escaping". Which would be replacing all the special characters that browsers interpret as HTML, such as replacing < and > with &lt; and &gt; respectively.
I assume if you replace the line with the following it should work:
<?php echo $term->description; ?>

You can learn more about when and how to use this function here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/

Thanks for the answer, unfortunately that didn't solve the problem :( Edited to code to reflect your changes!

Could you share an example of what the contents of $term->description would look like? That would help narrow down what your actual problem is.

Of course: The content is an adres like: Street & house nr  Postcode  City  Extra informatie like which venue hall.
